# Recursively create nested object with dynamic keys

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

I'm comfortable with recursion, but came across a case where I need to create nested objects with variable keys. Have seen other suggestions to use a namespace convention like 'b.c' to figure out where to assign values deeply (see desired output below), but having difficulty with implementation. The structure can be infinitely nested.

```js
// Source
const input = {
  a: {
    type: 'string',
    ex: '1'
  },
  b: {
    type: 'object',
    another: {
      c: {
        type: 'string',
        ex: '2'
      }
    }
  }
}

// Desired
const output = {
  a: '1',
  b: {
    c: '2'
  }
}

// The attempt
function traverse(data, master = {}) {
  Object.entries(data).reduce((collection, [key, value]) => {
    switch (value.type) {
      case 'string':
        collection[key] = value.ex;
        break;
      default:
        collection[key] = traverse(value.another, collection);
    }
    return collection;
  }, master);
}
```

Running this returns `undefined`.

Comment: Is `another` a fixed name?  If not, why is the expected result not `{a: '1', b: {another: {c: '2'}}}`?

Comment: The keys another, ex and type are all fixed and repeat themselves in the source data structure - its actually the structure of an open api spec but I swapped the keys to these to make it simpler for the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested `traverse` should get a brand new object as second parameter, you also need to return a retult from your function, try:

```js
// Source
const input = {
  a: {
    type: 'string',
    ex: '1'
  },
  b: {
    type: 'object',
    another: {
      c: {
        type: 'string',
        ex: '2'
      }
    }
  }
}


// The attempt
function traverse(data, master = {}) {
  return Object.entries(data).reduce((collection, [key, value]) => {
    switch (value.type) {
      case 'string':
        collection[key] = value.ex;
        break;
      default:
        collection[key] = traverse(value.another, {});
    }
    return collection;
  }, master);
}

console.log(traverse(input));
```